# How can I build a complementary array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of numbers corresponding to indices of another array.

```
index_array = np.array([2, 3, 5])
```

What I want to do is to create another array with the numbers `0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9`. What I have thought is:

```
index_list = []
for i in range(10):
    if i not in index_array:
        index_list.append(i)
```

This works but I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do it or even a built-in function for it.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking. You say the first array is indexes? So you want to remove these indices from another array? Or do you just want to create a range without those *values*?  Do you just want a range without the numbers in the first?

Comment: I use the first array to give some values to another array. For example `array[index_array]=57` and I want the other array just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is just to remove unwanted indices from the set:

```
n = 10
index_array = [2, 3, 5]
complement = np.delete(np.arange(n), index_array)
```

Comment: I've tried this and is faster than the other one and for what I'm going to use it, it works perfectly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) to efficiently collect the unique value from a "universal array" that aren't in your index array. Passing `assume_unique=True` provides a small speed up.
When `assume_unique` is `True`, the result will be sorted so long as the input is sorted.

```
import numpy as np

# "Universal set" to take complement with respect to.
universe = np.arange(10)

a = np.array([2,3,5])

complement = np.setdiff1d(universe, a, assume_unique=True)
print(complement)
```

Results in

```
[0 1 4 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like overkill given that your set is a contiguous range of integers